# ocijdbc11 Not found in java.library.path

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, aix, oracle-call-interface

I inherited a small java utility from other developer -- just a couple of .java files and executable .jar.

I run java program by passes a connection string. Now I need to change the connection string to Oracle from `jdbc:oracle:thin:<user>/<password>@host` to `jdbc:oracle:oci:<user>/<password>@host` to start using thick instead of thin driver.

As a result I get the error: "ocijdbc11 (Not found in java.library.path)".

Here my questions:

1. Is ocijdbc11 a part of ojdbc7.jar? Or what file do java need?
   ANSW: ocijdbc11 is a library: `/oracle/client/o11r2/lib/libocijdbc11.so`
2. How can I see which paths java uses to find that `ocijdbc11`?

Just in case:

```
$ ls /oracle/client/o12r1/

assistants     diagnostics    jlib           oui            slax
bin            dmu            ldap           owm            sqlplus
cdata          has            lib            perl           srvm
cfgtoollogs    hs             network        plsql          ucp
clone          install        nls            precomp        usm
crs            instantclient  odbc           QOpatch        utl
css            inventory      OPatch         racg           wwg
cv             javavm         opmn           rdbms          xdk
dc_ocm         jdbc           oracore        relnotes
deinstall      jdk            oraInst.loc    root.sh
```

**UPD** I tried to use option `-Djava.library.path=/oracle/client/o11r2` and got other error. But I still don't know how to use Oracle 12.1 instead of 11.2.

**UPD2** I've changed environment paths to use Oracle 12 instead of 11. And now error looks like `ocijdbc12 (Not found in java.library.path)`. The file /oracle/client/o12r1/lib/libocijdbc12.so exists.

I added `/oracle/client/o11r2/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` -- the same error (`ocijdbc12 (Not found in java.library.path)`). I tried option `-Djava.library.path=/oracle/client/o12r2/lib` -- the same error. Could you please help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

ocijdbc11 is a native libary (.so or .dll) which you can download from the Oracle Instant Client. It's the layer that contains the JNI calls into the OCI. This library is needed if you want to use the thick driver. Be sure to install the version that matches your ojdbc jar (i.e. it looks like you're using the JDBC jar from 11.2 otherwise if you were using ojdbc jar from 12.1 the error would have complained about ocijdbc12 missing).

Comment: "it looks like you're using the JDBC jar from 11.2" -- Yes, I suppose so. But how can I change path to 12.1? Is it just some environment variable or should I recompile java program?

Comment: You don't need to recompile. Just replace the JDBC jar with the one from 12.1 or 12.2 which you can download from the Oracle JDBC Download Page. Note that the one from 12.2 only works with JDK8 or later (JDK7 won't be supported).

Comment: " Just replace the JDBC jar with the one from 12.1" -- replace where? Java uses Oracle 11.2, but I want it to use 12.1(

Comment: Look in your classpath to see which JDBC jar you're currently using and replace it with the newer driver if needed.

Answer (score 0):

To run your program, you will need both `ojdbcN.jar` and `libocijdbcM.so`. These components have to come from the same Oracle-client; *N* refers to the Java version, *M* refers to the Oracle-version.

Of course you will need `libclntsh.so` and its dependent libraries, too.

You could try this (supposing java7, 64-bit):

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/client/o12r1
export LIBPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
java -cp $ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib/ojdbc7.jar:... -Djava.library.path=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
```

Edit: the java executable and the libraries should have the same bitnumber (32 or 64), eg this combination will not work:

```
$ file $JAVA_HOME/bin/java $ORACLE_HOME/lib/libclntsh.so $ORACLE_HOME/lib/libocijdbc12.so
/usr/java6/bin/java: executable (RISC System/6000) or object module not stripped
/orabin/OraHome_Current/lib/libclntsh.so: 64-bit XCOFF executable or object module not stripped
/orabin/OraHome_Current/lib/libocijdbc12.so: 64-bit XCOFF executable or object module not stripped
```

Here java is of 32-bit, Oracle is of 64-bit.

Edit: This question is flagged AIX. Is that intentional?

Comment: Everything is like you wrote... but still doesn't work(

Comment: Kindly edit you post and paste the relevant lines... Or attach as a file or something...